Using Slip Rings to implement a Swerve Drive system?
Would it be feasible to build a swerve drive system using slip rings?
For example, the wheel and its drive motor would be located below and attached to the "turn-able" part of the slip ring. Power for the motor would, of course, come from the slip ring wires.
The turn-able part of the slip ring would be driven (turned) by a stepper motor located above, attached to the base of the robot chassis.
Thank you.

If the slip rings can deliver the current and all signals, allow enough rotational speed, and there is enough budget, seems feasible to me.
